# Javascript 'this' reference - Can someone explain the simple example?

Tags: javascript, this

I'm doing a dive into JavaScript, and I am struggling to understand 'this' references in actual code. Could someone explain the 'this' reference in the following example?

```
$('#myimage').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).effect('bounce',500);
});​
```

I understand that the 'this' keyword refers to whatever 'owns' the declaring function. That means that in the following code, the 'this' would refer to the object that is returned by the objectFunction function:

```
var objectFunction = function() 
    {
        var thing = function() { alert(this.toString());  };

        return { thing : thing };
    }
objectFunction().thing();
```

Now in the first code, the 'this' keyword actually refers to the DOM element 'myimage'. What I can't work out is how I would determine that through inspection of the JavaScript. Can someone explain this?

Comment: This link might help - http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event in your example is handled by jQuery, not by the Javascript engine. In Javascript, it is possible to set what 'this' refers to when calling a function. jQuery uses the .apply method on a function to do this. So when jQuery interprets the selector, it will call your handler function for each matched object, setting 'this' to that matched object. E.g.

```
var handler = function() { alert(this.id) }

handler.apply(document.getElementById('something'));
```

In the above example, the 'this' inside the handler will refer to the dom element with the id of "something", and the alert will show the text "something".

Comment: OK, so it is not clear by introspection from the code alone. Rather, it requires knowledge of how jQuery calls 'event handlers.' Is that correct? That means, in general, you can't be sure from introspection alone what the 'this' reference will be in the body of an anonymous function passed to an external library?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the anonymous function is an event handler. The `this` keyword will refer to whatever element triggered the event. In this case, this can only be the element with the id `myimage`, because the event is bound to that element only. This is not necessarily the case; consider the following variant:

```
$('img').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).effect('bounce',500);
});​
```

This code will attach the mouse-enter event handler to all image tags in the document. So `this` could potentially refer to any image in the document; it depends on which image was 'touched' by the mouse cursor.